# Pine Editor exiting trade on next candle error

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am trying out a DMI + RSI reversal strategy in the Pine Editor in TradingView, but the trades keep exiting on the next bar even though it shouldn't be based on my criteria. Does anyone know what is causing this issue? I have also tried changing up the criteria for exiting the trade (I switched it from checking to see if the diplus was above or below 60 or 10, respectively, to try to see if the RSI was overbought or oversold by seeing if the value was above 70 or below 30, respectively). Even when I changed the criteria to exit, it was still exiting on the next candle right after it had entered the trade.

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI-14, DI+, DI- Reversal Strategy", overlay=false)


/// DI+ DI- Code /// /// DI+ is the variable called "plus" and DI- is the variable called "minus"

///// INPUTS /////
adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing")
dilen = input(14, title="DI Length")
//keylevel = input(23, title = "Key Level for ADX")
//adxLookbackEntry = input(3, title="Lookback Period for Slope (Entry)")
//adxLookbackExit = input(1, title="Lookback Period for Slope (Exit)")


[diplus, diminus, adx] = dmi(dilen, adxlen)

//buysignal = (adx[0] - adx[adxLookbackEntry] > 0) and adx > keyLevel and diplus > diminus
//shortsignal = (adx[0] - adx[adxLookbackEntry] > 0) and adx > keyLevel and diplus < diminus


//dirmov(len) =>
//  up = change(high)
//  down = -change(low)
//  plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
//  minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
//  truerange = rma(tr, len)
//  plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
//  minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
//  [plus, minus]
//adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
//  [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
//  sum = plus + minus
//  adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)
//sig = adx(dilen, adxlen)
//plot(sig, color=color.red, title="ADX")


///// RSI Code /////
rsi = rsi(close,14)
//rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsi_ob = rsi >= 70
rsi_os = rsi <= 30


///// MovAvg Code /////
sma5 = sma(close,5)
sma200 = sma(close,200)


////////// Strategy Entries and Exits ////////// 

//long the ticker//
minus_ob = diminus >= 60
plus_long_reversal = diplus[1] <= 10 and diplus[1] < diplus
minus_long_reversal = diminus[1] >= 60 and diminus[1] > diminus
exit_long_trade = diplus >= 60

//short the ticker//
plus_short_reversal = diplus[1] >= 60 and diplus[1] > diplus
minus_short_reversal = diminus[1] <= 10 and diminus[1] < diminus
exit_short_trade = diplus <= 10


isLongEntry = rsi_os and plus_long_reversal and minus_long_reversal
isLongExit = exit_short_trade
isShortEntry = rsi_ob and plus_short_reversal and minus_short_reversal// and close < open
isShortExit = exit_long_trade


t = time(timeframe.period, "0830-1500")
session_open = na(t) ? false : true

if (session_open)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 100.0, when = isLongEntry)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 100.0, when = isShortEntry)
    
    strategy.close("Long", when = isLongExit)
    strategy.close("Short", when = isShortExit)
//else
//    strategy.close_all()




rsi_graph_correction = 30
level_70 = 70-rsi_graph_correction
level_70rsi = rsi_graph_correction > level_70 ? rsi_graph_correction : level_70
level_30 = 30-rsi_graph_correction
level_30rsi = rsi_graph_correction < level_30 ? rsi_graph_correction: level_30

di_line_1 = hline(price=60,color=color.blue)
di_line_2 = hline(price = 10, color=color.yellow)

line_1 = hline(price=50-rsi_graph_correction)
line_2 = hline(price=70-rsi_graph_correction, color=color.red)
line_3 = hline(price=30-rsi_graph_correction,color=color.green)
p1 = plot(series = level_70, color=color.red, linewidth=1, transp=100)
p2 = plot(series = level_70rsi, color=color.red, linewidth=1, transp=100)
p3 = plot(series = level_30, color=color.green, linewidth=1, transp=100)
p4 = plot(series = level_30rsi, color=color.green, linewidth=1, transp=100)
p5 = plot(rsi-rsi_graph_correction,color=color.gray, transp=50)
p6 = plot(diplus,color=color.green)
p7 = plot(diminus,color=color.red)
//plotshape(isLongEntry, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.green, location=location.bottom)
plotshape(isLongEntry, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.green, location=location.bottom)
plotshape(isShortEntry, style=shape.arrowdown, color=color.red, location=location.top)


bgcolor(session_open ? color.green : na)

barcolor(isLongEntry ? color.blue : na)
barcolor(isLongExit ? color.purple : na)
barcolor(isShortEntry ? color.aqua : na)
barcolor(isShortExit ? color.yellow : na)
```

Any help is appreciated in figuring out the issue

Comment: This doesn't generate any signals on the tickers I tried it on. Which ticker are you using?

Comment: I am using this on the SPY 5m chart. It entered 4 trades. You actually answered another question of mine today that had to do with the same script (accessing the "plus" and "minus" variables through a global scope) and by adding those lines of code, it fixed the issue. I had attempted to use the built-in DMI function provided by TradingView, but it was causing an error with the values. I am pasting the link to the page where you answered my other question related to this script and eliminates this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791920/cant-access-value-from-function-in-pine-editor

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be in the built-in DMI function that grabs the diplus and diminus values. Here is a link to another post where I was having issues with this code (albeit another issue, yet it solves this problem) with a few different lines of code. It is better to create the values of the DMI manually instead of using TradingView's built in DMI function. Here is the link to the code posted by the user Bjorn Mistiaen (he commented on this post as well):
[can't access value from function in pine editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791920/cant-access-value-from-function-in-pine-editor)